# iPad built in dictionary for development

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I'm fairly new to iOS and was wondering if there was a way that I could search for a word in a game and pull up a definition. I have a splitviewcontroller, one view is moving objects for the game (irrelevant to the dictionary portion) and the other view is for the dictionary.

Does the iPad/iPhone have built in dictionaries for different languages, not just English that I could use?

I was thinking I could also use a site like http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hello and search it but I don't know what that would look like while the app is running (ie,if it would search it and display it in the viewcontroller instead of popping up a window).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `UIReferenceLibraryDictionaryController` (described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIReferenceLibraryViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)) uses the device's language.

Comment: Hi! Thank you I just looked it up and it does search definitions. however, it only takes in English words and several words from other languages (such as ciao, hola, signor etc). Still searching for a way to make a dictionary that will input non English, but output the definition in English.

Comment: @VC9 did you try changing the device language setting first?

Comment: @VC9 ah ha.  I missed the part where you want the output to always be in English.  In that case, you are basically asking for a translation service.  I would use something external for that.